# Call different Text under Footer-Wordpress-PHP

Tags: php, wordpress

Im trying to have different text appear under the footer bar, per page on my WP site.

I create a new footer(s) uploaded it and edited the page.php
and replaced the get_footer with this code here:

```
<?php if ( is_page('11') ) { ?>
<?php include(TEMPLATEPATH.'/footer2.php');?>
<?php } else { ?>
<?php include(TEMPLATEPATH.'/footer.php');?>
<?php } ?>
```

It works as I need it for doing the one page. I need to add a few more pages though. Everything I try adding to the above code for more pages doesnt work. Im not good at php so can someone explain the correct way to add to this?

Edit:
Changed it all to this. This is my page php.

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
        <?php get_sidebar('top'); ?>
        <?php

        if (have_posts()) {
            /* Start the Loop */
            while (have_posts()) {
                the_post();
                get_template_part('content', 'page');
            }
        } else {
            theme_404_content();
        }
        ?>
        <?php get_sidebar('bottom'); ?>
<?php get_footer( $page->11 ); ?>
```

This is the error I get
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_LNUMBER, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or '{' or '$' in /home/content/path/removed/page.php on line 16

Comment: post what you have tried that didn't work.

Comment: try switch statement, switch(postid) { case 11 : include "one.php"; break; } and so on..

Answer (score 1):

You can add different footers in pages using [`get_footer`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_footer):

```
<?php get_footer('2'); ?>
```

This will include `footer-2.php`.

Comment: Thanks but I dont follow. Do I use this in place of what I have or replace the second line with it instaed of what I have?

Comment: What I have works fine for the one page I added, I cant add more pages as I dont know how to add more correctly.

Answer (score 0):

If you want more pages with footer2, pass array to is_page function:

```
<?php if ( is_page(array('11', '12', '13', '14')) ) { ?>
```

Comment: I dont want more pages with this footer I need to add a footer3 to a different page

Answer (score 0):

You can replace your whole if clause with a single line:

```
<?php get_footer( $post->ID ); ?>
```

Now PHP will look for a file named `footer-<pageid>.php`. For example: If you want to use a custom footer file for a page with the ID 11, just name the file `footer-11.php`. Wordpress will use it on this page, on all other pages it will fall back to the default `footer.php`

Comment: Great thanks im trying it. I think I messed up. I replaced what I had with what you have, renamed the footer to footer-11.php.

Comment: The site just gives an error though now. I changed post to page als if that matters.

Comment: edit your question and post the code you have now. also the error message.

Comment: Thanks for the help Gerald. I did as asked. edited post included information.

Comment: you need to use `$post->ID`, not `$page->11`. $post holds the content of your page, ID holds the ID.

Comment: WOW. It works. I added a 2nd footer for a different page and it worked. SO basically I just add footer with page id, example(footer-45.php) and it assigns it to that page? COrrect?

Comment: I thank  you so much, huge help. Im going to add another just to try

Comment: Perfect. THANK YOU! Does excately what I was after